# Exclude a set of nodes picked in multinode tree picker from a Descendants Where() clause in Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I've setup a multinode treepicker to pick a set of nodes which I'm trying to exclude from a set of Descendants nodes.

I'm not sure about the Where() syntax to accomplish this:

```
var exclude_nodes = CurrentPage.pickedNodes;

var nodes = Model.Content.AncestorsOrSelf("homepage").First().Descendants("addonProduct").Where( filter out exclude_nodes here);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
new [] { 1, 2, 3 }.Where(x => x > 1) // { 2, 3 }
new [] { 1, 2, 3 }.Except(new [] { 2, 3 }) // { 1 }
```

i.e. in your case

```
var nodes = ...Descendants("addonProduct").Except(exclude_nodes);
var nodes = ...Descendants("addonProduct").Where(d => !exclude_nodes.Contains(d));
```

Please note Except() behavior:

```
new [] { 1, 1, 2, 3 }.Except(new [] { 2 }) // { 1, 3 }
```

Comment: Could you ellaborate a bit on how I would implement this with my set of nodes picked from the multietree picker above?   I'm very new to Umbraco so still learning.

my exclude_nodes contains the data from the multinode tree picker which I want to exclude from the query used in "nodes" variable.

Comment: Only note here is that the original poster would need to alter the part where they get the nodes to exclude, as they're mixing dynamics and strongly typed Umbraco nodes in their code, so the descendants will never contain the exclude nodes, as they're different types. Something like: var exclude_nodes = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("pickedNodes"); should work.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks alot :)